# Why does the first bitcoin client only supported windows

Tags: bitcoin-core, linux, windows, history, open-source

Starting from version 0.1.0 up to 0.1.5 the bitcoin software could be run only on only Windows 2000 / Windows NT and Windows XP

Was there a technical reason from Satoshi for this choice of operating system, or maybe he wanted his client to be run on the maximum amount of computer, or maybe he had more knowledge of windows ? Linux seem more fit for open source and "Cypherpunk" that windows.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a definitive answer, you'll need to ask him I'm afraid.

My best guess is that Windows development was the thing he was most familiar with (or even only familiar with). The coding style was also similar to one commonly used in the 90's by Windows developers.